I am unable to find a match using Pattern.matcher()
I am trying to find the string that starts and ends both with "1" and only has "0" in between(could have no zero). How to write regex to get the matched substring?
Why this code doesn't work?
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(10*1)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(binaryString);
        while(m.find()){
            System.out.println(m.group(1)); 
        }

e.g. input: 1101, output: 101, 11

Do you want overlapping matches? (?=(10*1)) https://regex101.com/r/7Zilt0/1

In what way does it not work? Please post a complete runnable piece of code, the input you're trying, the expected output and the actual output.

@Thefourthbird thanks, it worked. But why (10*1) doesn't work? it only finds 11 for string 1101, not 101

@HuaLiang Because for the string "1101" the regex 10*1 first consumes "11" and then "01" is left. When using 10*1 for the string "01" there is no match.

@Thefourthbird nice. Appreciated

@Thefourthbird  Clearly I am missing something but if one had 111111 as input and was using the pattern (111) it would simply find 111 and 111 as it consumes the  1's and starts after the first match ended.  But if one uses a zero width lookahead it would find all four 111 matches.  But it is zero-width.   So why does it consume anything and not result in an endless loop?

@WJS Because the current position advances 1 position after the match. The value that you capture is in a capture group, which you can use in a lookahead assertion. See https://regex101.com/r/R5bDX9/1

@Thefourthbird Ah, so the next position is size + 1.  Of course.  Thanks!

I think this pattern suitable for your scinario
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=1)(0*?)(?=1)");


You need to explain your answer and show input and output examples..  Don't just post a solution ( assuming it works).
